# how to add slider in data list asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, slider, html-lists, datalist

Need to show just booked work order binded values using data list from db every 30seconds timer will run method to bind data list need to slide datalist when last work order different with new work order otherwise no need to slider need the output like below website www.booking.com (just Booked ) 
my problem is unable to slide single li one by one i tried with vticker.js and easyslider.js plugin but facing same issue sliding all ul not one by one

```
<div id="example" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 440px;">
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updBookedNote" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
      <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
      </Triggers>
      <ContentTemplate>
         <ul style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 0px;">
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Enabled="true" />
            <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dlUsersListing" RepeatDirection="Vertical" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Name="Verdana" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Font-Size="10pt">
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <table id="tblMenu" width="30%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" runat="server" border="0">
                     <li style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 90px;">
                        <tr style="height: 33px;">
                           <td>
                              <table id="Table2" class="previewsBooked1" runat="server">
                                 <tr style="height: 33px;">
                                    <td rowspan="2" style="width: 25px;">
                                       <div class="previewsIcon">
                                          <img align="middle" width="40px" src="App_Themes/Default/Images/login/arrow_gren_bri.png" />
                                       </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                       <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" CssClass="labelclam" Text="Claim #"></asp:Label>
                                       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkserviceorder" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" CssClass="labelclam" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Service Order #" ) %>' PostBackUrl='<%#"~/WorkOrder/ServiceOrder.aspx?CustWorkOrdNo=" +Eval("Service Order #")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                       <span style="text-align: left">
                                          <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" CssClass="labelclam" Text="From"></asp:Label>
                                          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" CssClass="labelregion" Text='<%# Eval("region")%>'> ></asp:Label>
                                       </span>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr style="height: 33px;">
                                    <td>
                                       <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" CssClass="labelblue" Text="Just Booked by"></asp:Label>
                                       <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" CssClass="labelGray1" Text='<%# Eval("Account Name")%>'> ></asp:Label>
                                       <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" CssClass="labelblue" Text="for"></asp:Label>
                                       <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" CssClass="lbluppercase" Text='<%# Eval("district")%>'> ></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                              </table>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </li>
                  </table>
               </ItemTemplate>
</ul>
</asp:DataList>
      </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Comment: I re-formatted your code. Please show some respect to the people you ask for help and format your code in future so it can be easily read. While formatting the code I noticed you open your `<ul>` outside the `<asp:DataList>` and close it **inside** the `<asp:DataList>` tag. See the two non-indented lines in my modified revision. I can't tell if that causes your problem but sure you first should fix it.

Comment: I already tried. Did you check if fixing the issue I mentioned helps? From my understanding (basically none of ASP) your code would produce a closing `</ul>` tag for every item. Also, it appears you have a table in your `<ul>`? That is no valid HTML. A `<ul>` may only contain `<li>` elements.

Comment: i correct my code from what u said,yes none of ASP code would produce a closing '</UL>' tag for every item,but am getting separate '<Li></Li>' for every item

Comment: did you checked the website <www.booking.com> for reference